# Where can I find documentation on escape characters like "\"

Tags: r

I'd like to gain a better understanding of escape character sequences in R. I've tried searching for things like `?'\'` but, that escapes itself and `?'\\'`

I'd like to avoid this kind of behaviour with `cat()`. For example:

```
cat("\")
+
```

Versus:

```
cat("\\")
\
```

Comment: 'The R Inferno' talks about this and similar traps http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The help page you are looking for is `?Quotes` (with the capital Q).  String literal syntax is also described (less clearly IMHO) at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Literal-constants.

The backslash escape works very nearly the same as it does in C and all the other languages that borrowed backslash escapes from C -- `\n` inserts a newline, `\\` inserts a single backslash, `\"` in a double quoted string prevents the `"` from ending the string, etc.