# R: What is the escape character for braceleft { and braceright } in a string

Tags: r

Do you know which escape characters are needed for braceleft { and braceright } in a string?

"{" and "}" do not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on escape characters like "\"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271208/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-escape-characters-like)

Comment: Questions should have complete minimal (i.e. cut down to a small size while still illlustrating the problem) self contained code (i.e. including all inputs and library statements) so that others can paste it into their session and observe the problem too.   Also discuss what the problem is and what is expected.

Comment: You need to use \\ in front of each brace - for example -  `grep("\\{ \\}, string)`

Comment: No escape needed sorry for asking but I tried escape "\{" and "\}" and got error. So { and  } do not to be escaped in strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braceleft { and braceright } do not need any escape. So you can use "{" and "}" in strings.

It was problematically because I used it in a regex using function `nsub` and made some mistakes.